# Using JQuery variable inside JQuery script instead of numbers

Tags: jquery, variables

So I have this script.

```
     if (content == same){
              wait=wait+1;
     }

     if (wait > 10){
             polltime = 6000;
     }

     if (content != same){
             $('#mydiv').load('content.php');
     }
}, 2000);
```

This works fine and there isnt any issue. However, if I try change the number 2000 to "polltime" like this

```
    if (content == same){
            wait=wait+1;
    }

    if (wait > 10){
            polltime = 6000;
    }

    if (content != same){
            $('#mydiv').load('content.php');
    }
}, polltime);
```

the script stops running. How do I utilize the variable like this? Sorry for this question, I am new to JQuery!

Comment: ``polltime`` should have a value when ``wait <= 10``

Comment: It's clear that there is some more code before your `if (content == same)`: you had better include that too, because the last row of your code forces me to think that the problem is related to what is acting before your initial `if` statement!

Comment: Is this in a `setInterval()` call? A `setTimeout()`? Where and when is `polltime` declared and initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Your var is NOT in scope anymore. Try to define your variable BEFORE you use the function so you can keep it in scope:

```
var polltime = 0;

function my_function(){
 if (content == same){
          wait=wait+1;
 }

 if (wait > 10){
         polltime = 6000;
 }

 if (content != same){
         $('#mydiv').load('content.php');
 }
}, polltime);
```

So the function will execute and replace the value of "polltime". At the end, if wait>10 "polltime" will have a value of 6000.

Comment: Thank you. This does not seem to work. Polltime remains 0 even though I instruct it to update to 6000.

Comment: At the time you start the function polltime will be 0, at the time the function exits polltime will be 6000. The thing is, if you want to change a value that you already used at runtaime is juts not possible. This is because when the function was fired it took polltime value in that time which it was, 0.